# Bought an iPhone 6 from a friend - iCloud question

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

The phone was wiped but they left their AppleID logged in. I deleted their AppleID and their iCloud account from the phone and replaced it with my own.

Will my stuff still go to their iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by you've deleted their Apple ID and iCloud account from the phone, but if you've fully signed out of all services (i.e. Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes and App Store) then you're on the right track.

However, your friend needed to follow some steps before selling you their phone. According to Apple, [this is what someone should do before they sell or give away their iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201351).

I would start again by getting together with your friend and double-checking that everything is done the way it should be.

Comment: Yes everything is in my name now, icloud, apple id, iTunes, app store. My friend lives far away so we can't get together. After I signed into my apple id I reset the phone again. So does that mean that none of my stuff will go to there icloud?

Comment: As a friend they would tell you if they had stuff appear in their account that was yours...

Comment: As long as everything is logged into *your* account and nothing is logged into *their* account you should be fine. If you're not 100% sure, you could get your friend to sign into iCloud.com on another device and if the iPhone is still listed there they can opt to remove it from their account.